# Isolating $t$ on a parametric function

Tags: parametric, curves, plane-curves

I have to plot the graph of
$$\gamma(t)=(4t^2-4t,1-4t^2)$$
for $t\in\mathbb{R}$.

I tried to isolate $t$ in $x=4t^{2}-4t$ (or for $y=1-4t^2$), but in this case, I got something with square root. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: For elimination of $t,$ use $$x+y=?\iff t=?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint.** Eliminate $t$ and get that 
$$
{x}^{2}-2\,xy+{y}^{2}+2\,x+2\,y-3=0.
$$